# Why even after getting response status as 200 , I am not able to get connect to websocket in PostMan?

Tags: java, websocket, webclient

```
Could not connect to ws://localhost:8081/message
00:22:19
Error: Unexpected server response: 200
Handshake Details
Request URL: http://localhost:8081/message
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Request Headers
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: RRr0MEMeU8Shs/3Z+j9w/g==
Connection: upgrade
Upgrade: $http_upgrade
Host: localhost:8081
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Response Headers
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=533006AA29B1FA7D3C103AC027D327A5; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1406
Date: Wed, 22 Mar 2023 18:52:19 GMT
```

I am trying to listen to message from one particular destination , As I am not having FE . I am using postman to check it.

Answer (score 0):

A websocket client is not expecting a 200 response code. Instead it will expect a 101 response code which indicates that the server wants the client to switch protocols. I strongly suggest that if you are going to implement websockets that you use a library on the server side to handle the websocket handshake rather than trying to implement the protocol yourself. If you post which language your server is in, we can direct you to an appropriate library.

Comment: My backend part is in springboot though.Can you help me out.

Comment: @Ashraf If your backend is using Spring boot then I suggest you use the Spring boot websocket starter kit. You can find a complete guide to implementing this using the STOMP protocol (which is a great idea since it provides additional abstraction on top of websockets) https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/ Good luck!